# Connect Excel VBA macro with KEPServer: DDERequest error 2023

Tags: excel, vba, opc, kepserverex

Some versions of Windows computers can connect.

I'm using Windows 10, Excel 2010 and KEPServer 5.13. The macro used to work, so a Windows update must have made it fail.

A DDERequest returns the Error 2023.

Also KEPServer gives the following error:

```
Date        Time         Level        Source                      Event
21/01/2020  16:57:23     Error        DDE                         Attempt to add DDE item 'TOOL1.PLC.MESCADA_BoxProductionCounter' failed.
```

VBA code:

```vb
Private Sub Establish_Connection_Click()

    Dim Tmp_Old_BoxProductionCounter As Variant
    
    RSIchan = DDEInitiate("kepdde", "_ddedata")
    
    Estat_Conexio.Text = " Connected to hardware "
    
    Mode = "Automatic"
    
    Tmp_Old_BoxProductionCounter = DDERequest(RSIchan, "TOOL1.PLC.MESCADA_BoxProductionCounter")'<-- It fails here   
    
    Old_BoxProductionCounter = Tmp_Old_BoxProductionCounter(1)
    
    Call Worksheet_Activate
    collected_rows = 2
  
    Initiate_Study.Enabled = False
    ...
```

It uses NetDDE to connect with the KEPServer. I know it is obsolete and  that might be the problem and there is a more modern way, using OLE, but I don't know how and if it will work.

Comment: Have you tried with another Office version?

Comment: Yes, I have used Office 2016 and it keeps returning the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with iot:P,The use of OPCUA or OPCDA requires the use of reasonable DDE components, and when these components are updated, there may be coordination problems between versions.

You can consider using MQTT or HTTP, which is a simpler and common way to obtain PLC data, such as using LECPServer (similar to Kepserver), but he can use HTTP protocol to read and write PLC content.

https://github.com/xeden3/LECPServer
https://lecpserver.com/feature/

The VBA code is as follows

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://172.10.26.11"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send "{""action"":""plc_read_node"", ""node"":""NODES.DEV01.D100""}"
sResp = oHttp.ResponseText
```